# Combined odds ratio

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I wonder if there's a way to calculate the combined odds ratio for certain SNPs in a meta-analysis of a several GWAS, even when you don't have the SE, neither beta, for each individual study?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the confidence interval? SE can be back calculated from that. Also, you say that you don't have the betas, but I suppose that you have the OR's. In that case the betas can be calculated by taking the natural logarithm of the OR's.

Comment: ...or the p-values? If you have precise p-values you can back-calculate SEs  from them.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you only have p-values for each SNP. In this case you can use [Fisher's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method), but it is a rather crude analysis. Not only will meta-analyzing betas and SEs give you better power, but it also permits estimation of an overall effect, which will be useful in many ways, not least planning replication studies.